# How to create sharepoint 2010 site programmatically based on site template

Tags: templates, sharepoint-2010

I am new to SharePoint my requirement is, we are developing a business intelligence dash board using pps with some custom reports built on it.

I need to replicate this site to create n no of subsites based on this bi dash board site. So I am planning to make this site as a site template and trying to create the site programmatically based on this site template. Can anyone help me how to achieve this.

Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

One of the overload of creating a site accepts a site template object. What you need to do is to retrieve this object iterating through the collection of the custom web templates of the site collection: SPSite.GetCustomWebTemplates. You just get the one you need by name

Comment: Hi Gubler,

Your solutions seems to be the apt thing for me as i am new to this sharepoint stuff can you eloborate me with more detail exploation with some real time example.

Comment: SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
var templates = site.GetCustomWebTemplates(1033); //change 1033 to your language
foreach(var template in templates)
{
if(template.Title="template name")
{
SPContext.Current.Web.Webs.Add("url", "title", "description", 1033, template, false, false);//change 1033 to your language
}
}